# Spring Security Rest API failure handler, how to get username?

Tags: spring, rest

We are using Spring security (4.2.x) for Rest API.

I am trying to get 'username' in the failure handler class (MyAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler) during a failed authentication.

Is there a way to get the 'username' for our internal follow on processing? This is not a web page call, it is a webservices REST API call (no browser involved)

I tried the following in vain

```
    String lUsername = request.getParameter("j_username");
    String lUsername1 = request.getRemoteUser();
    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String username = (String) 
    request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME");
```

Let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the username in the http header. If you are using basic authentication, it's in the `Authorization` field:

```
request.getHeaders().getHeader("Authorization");
```

You will get a string with this format:

```
Basic user:password
```